# python how to extract operators from string

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract operators like: `+,-,/,*` and also `(,),_` from the string

Eg.

```
a-2=b
(c-d)=3
```

output:

```
- ,=, (, -, ), =
```

This does not work:

```
re.finditer(r'[=+/-()]*', text)
```

Comment: You need to escape `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `re` needs to escape some of the characters with a backslash. (`+`, `-`, `(`, `)` have their special meanings in `re`).

Anyway, for this you don't need `re`:

```
(c for c in s if c in '+-/*()_')
```

Comment: Escaping is actually not an issue here, because they're using a character class.